# correct word order: $200 of sales tax" Or "sales tax of $200"

Tags: word-order

Which one of these is correct?

> -*"I paid **$200 of sales tax** on my computer."*
> -*"I paid **sales tax of $200** on my computer."*

Can anyone please explain me the correct word order.

Answer (score 1):

In financial transactions, we use the preposition **in** to categorise different parts of the total. For example, I might make a bank deposit of $100 in cash and $200 in cheques, giving a total of $300.

Here is an example relating to sales tax:

> Consider a simple example. A purchaser of $1000 worth of camping equipment, who resides in a state with a 5% sales and use tax, might consider three suppliers. Firm A is an in-state firm who must collect 5% ($50) **in sales tax**. - *[Interstate Sales Tax Collection Act of 1987](https://books.google.co.id/books?id=jxl7CQ7Au-QC&pg=PA575&dq=%22in%20sales%20tax%22&hl=id&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiD4oPd--_tAhVe7XMBHdBXA38Q6AEwAHoECAQQAg#v=onepage&q=%22in%20sales%20tax%22&f=false) (US Congress Subcommittee on Monopolies and Commercial Law)*

Answer (score -1):

I would think using "for" would be better:

> I paid $200 **for** sales tax on my computer.

"$200 of sales tax" sounds a bit strange; *for* means that the you spent $200 for paying the sales tax.